# How to merge or smooth layers of different sculpted objects without seams?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I tried using a *Boolean Modifier* with the *Union* operation between the layers seen below but it didn't work. I tried using the [`Snake Hook`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools/snake_hook.html) tool in combination with the *Boolean Modifier*, but that didn't work either.

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: If the body parts are created from different objects that have beem joined with Ctrl+J then you need do a remesh operation to get one solid object. Otherwise, they will be loose parts of the mesh that you cannot sculpt smoothly.

Comment: similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/84147/107598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I joined the objects and used Remesh(more specifically the voxel option)as suggested by @Blunder. After that, mirrored the objects that were joined and used the smooth tool to get rid of any seams left.