# how can I hide the seam after joining two meshes

Tags: mesh

I used the skin modifier to make my dino model but I had to separately make its hands. my problem is that it looks like the hands and the body are different parts, I wanted to know if there is way to hide it or make it better. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share the file?Remove the head if you don't want to share it entirely

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270081/how-to-merge-or-smooth-layers-of-different-sculpted-objects-without-seams

Comment: @johnEason Thank you so much it worked out perfectly!

Comment: @moonboots sorry I'll make sure to add the blender file next time I have a problem thanks for replying

Comment: @Thisewbasnayake You're welcome! You'd have been able to find it yourself if you'd used the "Search on Blender..." field at the top of this page! :^)